# How can i nest URLRouter in Django-Channels

Tags: django-channels

I have tried to use `django.urls.path` and `django.urls.include` to structure the URLs in the routing for *django-channels*.

Ex:

```py
from django.urls import path, include

from .browser import routing as browser_routing


websocket_urlpatterns = [
    path('ws/v2/', include([
        path('browser/', browser_routing.urls),
    ])),
]
```

```py
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from my_channels import routing

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            routing.websocket_urlpatterns,
        ),
    ),
})
```

But i got:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: : include() is not supported in URLRouter. Use
>   nested URLRouter instances instead.

I found the comment in the documentation but no examples: 
https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/releases/2.1.0.html?highlight=URLRouter#nested-url-routing

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using `include`, I was able to fix it by nesting `URLRouter`.

assuming that `browser_routing.urls` is also a set of nested `URLRouter`.

#### `urls.py`

```
from channels.routing import URLRouter

websocket_urlpatterns = URLRouter([
    path('ws/v2/', URLRouter([
        path('browser/', browser_routing.urls),
    ])),
])
```

#### `routing.py`

```
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(
        routing.websocket_urlpatterns,
    ),
})
```

Comment: This should be marked as correct for future viewers.